# eiffel: type is based on unknown class (even when visible into libraries)

Tags: include-path, eiffel, eiffel-studio-19.12

Trying to include a library I just created I'm unable to have the Class available even if it appears into the libraries on the group view of eiffel studio

[image]

### ../thirdparty/moon_time/sunriset_lib.ecf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<system xmlns="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0 http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0.xsd" name="sunriset" uuid="6E7AC452-4513-4BB4-9F04-A1ABCBCC1BE3" library_target="sunriset">
        <target name="sunriset">
                <root all_classes="true"/>
                <file_rule>
                        <exclude>/CVS$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/EIFGENs$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/\.git$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/\.svn$</exclude>
                </file_rule>
                <option warning="warning" manifest_array_type="mismatch_warning">
                        <assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>
                </option>
                <setting name="console_application" value="true"/>
                <setting name="total_order_on_reals" value="false"/>
                <setting name="dead_code_removal" value="feature"/>
                <library name="base" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\base\base.ecf"/>
                <library name="time" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\time\time.ecf"/>
                <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
        </target>
        <target name="sunriset_tests" extends="sunriset">
                <root class="APPLICATION" feature="make"/>
                <option warning="warning">
                        <assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>
                </option>
                <setting name="console_application" value="true"/>
                <library name="testing" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\testing\testing.ecf"/>
                <cluster name="test" location=".\testing\" recursive="true"/>
        </target>
</system>
```

### main-raspi-app.ecf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<system xmlns="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0 http://www.eiffel.com/developers/xml/configuration-1-21-0.xsd" name="main_raspi_app" uuid="CC76847A-99AA-4FAE-A27F-CFBA76A914AF">
        <target name="raspi_data_visitor">
                <root class="RASPI_DATA_VISITOR_APP" feature="make"/>
                <file_rule>
                        <exclude>/CVS$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/EIFGENs$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/\.git$</exclude>
                        <exclude>/\.svn$</exclude>
                </file_rule>
                <option warning="warning" manifest_array_type="mismatch_warning">
                        <assertions precondition="true" postcondition="true" check="true" invariant="true" loop="true" supplier_precondition="true"/>
                </option>
                <setting name="console_application" value="true"/>
                <setting name="executable_name" value="raspi_data_visitor"/>
                <setting name="dead_code_removal" value="feature"/>
                <library name="base" location="$ISE_LIBRARY\library\base\base.ecf"/>
                <library name="json" location=".\..\thirdparty\json\library\json.ecf" readonly="false"/>
                <library name="sit-platform" location=".\..\sit-platform\sit_platform_lib.ecf" readonly="false"/>
                <library name="sunriset" location=".\..\thirdparty\moon_time\sunriset_lib.ecf" readonly="false"/>
                <cluster name="src" location=".\src\" recursive="true"/>
        </target>
        <target name="raspi_data_generator" extends="raspi_data_visitor">
                <root class="RASPI_DATA_GENERATOR_APP" feature="make"/>
        </target>
</system>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

As the `SOLAR_NRJ_ADVISOR` class is part of the `sit-platform` **library**, I had to include the library into the `sit-platform` **library** instead of the current project
[image]